# Abnormal alexa ranking score

Tags: web, seo, e-commerce, google-ranking, alexa-internet

I have 2 websites of ecommerce in France and for these websites I have a strange behaviour of the alexa results. Here are some statistics about the websites :

**Unique Visits January 2012**

- Website A : 158,828
- Website B : 58,867

**Number of Search Results google**

- Website A : 5,100
- Website B : 56,000

**Links to my site**

- Website A : 3,120
- Website B : 2,180

**ALEXA Score**

- Website A : 405,804
- Website B : 278,944

How does it come that website B with 1/3 of the visitors of website A have a much better Alexa Score ( x2 ) then website A?

Comment: I squinted really hard, but still can't see how this is programming related. Perhaps you could try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @ShawnChin : Ok thanks, I didn't know there was webmasters.stackexchange.com ( so also thanks for this hint )

Comment: This Q has been posted and answered here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27898/abnormal-alexa-ranking-score. Glad you found a satisfactory answer, @Steenhouwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed else where (reddit) and I am writing this on the top of my head. Alexa toolbar is installed on certain browsers (IE <strike>sucks</strike> six), Alexa uses this specific sample for ranking. Reddit users where surprised to find a huge proportion of traffic from certain geographies like India than first world countries.

The unbiased ranking published may be the one taken at a larger scale using statistics from CDNs and Google analytics.

Answer (score -1):

For more accurate Alexa Rank you need a Certified Metrics, Certified Site Metrics are metrics that are directly-measured from the website instead of estimated.
Certified Metrics are only available with an Alexa Pro plan.

PS: Certifying your site’s metrics provides a more accurate rank, but not necessarily a better rank!